# How to handle events among multiple directives and a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm struggling to come up with the proper Angular idiom, and I felt the path I was going down is a non-pure on. To frame my scenario with a contrived example:

- Consider an Angular controller, called `AlbumController`.
- `AlbumController` has a scope property, which is an array of album objects:

  ```
  $scope.albums = [
    {
      title : "Album 1",
      artist : "Artist 1"
    },
    ...
  ]
  ```
- I'm using an `ng-repeat` paired with a custom directive to layout the albums:

  ```
  <div ng-repeat="album in albumns">
    <div fresh-album album="album"></div>
  </div>
  ```
- And the directive template is setting a property on that album object:

  ```
  module.directive('freshAlbum', function() {
    return {
      template : '<button ng-click="album.selected = !album.selected">Click</button>',
      scope : { album = '=' },
      ...
    };
  });
  ```
- Note, the reason for adding the `selected` attribute is that when an album is clicked, custom styles to indicate the album is selected, is added to the element.
- What I would like to do is: when an album is selected, **deselect** the other selected album (e.g., if album 1 is selected, and the user selects album 2, I need album 1 to deselect).

My initial thought for this was to have a `$watch` in `AlbumController` to monitor for album changes:

```
var selectedAlbum = -1;  // Keeping track of the currently selected album
$scope.$watch('albums', function(newValue) {
  angular.forEach($scope.albums, function(album, i) {
    if (selectedAlbum === -1 && album.selected) {
      selectedAlbum = i;      // No previously selected albums
    } else if (selectedAlbum === i && album.selected) {
      album.selected = false; // Previously selected album; deselect it
    } else if (album.selected) {
      selectedAlbum = i;      // Newly selected album
    }
  });
});
```

However, because I'm "de-selecting" albums in the `$watch` callback, it triggers another `$watch`, thus deselecting the newly selected album as well. At this point, I stopped, because I felt that I was approaching this wrong.

An alternative idea I had was to have the `freshAlbum` directive publish an "selection" event that the controller responds to. Is an approach like this more Angular-esque"?

Answer (score 2):

You can add an expression to directive which will be called whenever an album is clicked.

```
module.directive('freshAlbum', function() {   return {
    template : '<button ng-click="album.selected = !album.selected; albumIsClickedEvent();">Click</button>',
    scope : { album : '=' 
              albumIsClicked: "&"},
    ...   }; });

<div ng-repeat="album in albumns">
  <div fresh-album album="album" album-is-clicked="albumIsClickedEvent"></div>
</div>
```

And in your controller, you can implement albumIsClickedEvent function to do what you want to achieve (close the other open albums etc.).

Through this expression directive can communicate with an outer controller.

Comment: I would add this function as a second parameter to directive to make it smart.

Comment: Typically when I do something like this I just do everything in that method: `ng-click='select(album)'  So that one method would basically deselect all albums and then set the proper one to selected.

Comment: You are right; it is better to write the function in your directive declaration, rather than writing it as an inline function in your template.